# How to render one component per state-object in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am currently building an entry-based application to use for Pen-and-Paper stuff. The application should contain one entry per player with trackable properties.

In React, I created a parent "Entry" component, that contains multiple sub components for these properties, which are passed down to them.
On the highest level (= in the App component), I need to be able to add/remove these Entries dynamically.

I understood that I need to do this via state, so I decided to create an "entry" object in the state, which contains all required properties. To add or remove entries, I plan to simply add / remove further entry-objects in the state.

What I'm failing to do, is to render one -component per object in the state. My code looks like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    entry: {
      type: 0,
      name: "Default",
      init: 10,
      ...
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Entry
          type={this.state.entry.type}
          name={this.state.entry.name}
          init={this.state.entry.init}
          ...
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In Java, I'd need something like

```
for (entry : state) {
    return <Entry type={entry.type} ... />;
}
```

I found multiple solutions suggesting something with "map through the array", but {this.state.map} seems to be wrong.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your use case I think you should use an array to store your entries instead of an object:

```js
state = {
  entries: [
    {
      type: 0,
      // ... the properties that make up an entry
    }
  ]
};
```

What people have suggested you is to use the `map` method on an array. `map` will create a new array where each element in the original array has been *mapped* to some other value.

You can use this to map your array of entries to an array of React components (React will happily render an array).

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  state = {
    entries: [
      {
        title: 'First Entry',
      },
      {
        title: 'Second Entry',
      },
    ],
  };
  
  render() {
    // it is important to give each component a unique `key` property
    const mappedEntries = this.state.entries.map((entry) => (
      <li key={entry.title}>{ entry.title }</li>
    ));
    
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Entries:</h1>
        <ul>
          { mappedEntries }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Ah, I did not know that you have to use arrays for this mapping and lists were not possible. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can map throught your state/object keys :

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    entry: {
      type: 0,
      name: "Default",
      init: 10,
      ...
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {Object.keys(this.state).map(key => (
          <Entry {...this.state[key]} /> // spread properties of object
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Edit: I may have misunderstood your issue, if your need is to render "x" `<Entry />` components with the same properties where "x" is the number of `entry` keys you can do this :

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    entry: {
      type: 0,
      name: "Default",
      init: 10,
      ...
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {Object.keys(this.state.entry).map(key => (
          <Entry {...this.state.entry} /> // spread properties of object
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```